# How to improve the performance of the SQL query which uses table variable which has more than 50k entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, table-variable

I have to update two temp tables `@tbNewEntry` and `@tbUpdateEntry` from another temp table `@OnlineDataBase` (I got the Data from online into this table) based on some conditions.

Conditions to update:

- Update `@tbNewEntry` if CityCode is **not present** in your Local DB (LocalFunction returns the list of City codes. This function is just inner join of two other tables)
- Update `@tbUpdateEntry` if CityCode **is Present** in Local DB but the CityName is not matching with `@OnlineDataBase`.

I followed some points from Google and created the required indexes. But still not able to improve the performance.

Guide me to improve the performance of following the query. The tables have millions of records.

```
DECLARE @OnlineDataBase TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),CityCode NVARCHAR(10),CityName NVARCHAR(MAX),Area INT,  Population INT);
DECLARE @tbNewEntry TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),CityCode NVARCHAR(10),CityName NVARCHAR(MAX),Area INT,  Population INT);
DECLARE @tbUpdateEntry TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),CityCode NVARCHAR(10),CityName NVARCHAR(MAX),Area INT,  Population INT);


INSERT INTO @tbNewEntry(CityCode,CityName,Area,Population)
SELECT TN.CityCode, TN.CityName, TN.Area, TN.Population
FROM @OnlineDataBase TN WHERE TN.CityCode NOT IN (SELECT CityLocalDB.CityCode IN FROM LocalFunction as CityLocalDB)


INSERT INTO @tbUpdateEntry(CityCode,CityName,Area,Population)
SELECT TN.CityCode, TN.CityName, TN.Area, TN.Population
FROM @OnlineDataBase TN WHERE TN.CityCode IN (SELECT CityLocalDB.CityCode IN FROM LocalFunction as CityLocalDB
WHERE TN.CityName !=CityLocalDB.CityName )
```

Comment: Table variables are very different animals to temp tables, especially on older versions of SQL Server that always estimate table variables as containing 1 row.

Comment: Can you show us what are you going to do with `@tbNewEntry` and `@tbUpdateEntry` ? It might be more efficient to perform the insert or update directly to your final table rather than going through table variables

Comment: Table variables should not be used when performance is required. You want an actual temp table.

Comment: Agree with @DaleK, go with temp tables.

Comment: Also remember, after setting them up as #temp tables rather than @table variables, you can then add primary keys and indexes to the tables to improve the performance of further queries. For example, I'd consider (at face value) removing the ID field, and make the CityCode the Primary key (or at least clustered index). You may also want to consider/test the effect of the CityName field size (current nvarchar max) as it can affect estimates and processing.

Comment: For performance help, we need to see your table and index definitions, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com. The question is not answerable otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You should change the variable table to temporary temp table
because variable table has a fixed value for cardinality estimate

```
CREATE  TABLE #tbNewEntry (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),CityCode NVARCHAR(10),CityName NVARCHAR(MAX),Area INT,  Population INT);
CREATE TABLE #tbUpdateEntry (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),CityCode NVARCHAR(10),CityName NVARCHAR(MAX),Area INT,  Population INT);


INSERT INTO #tbNewEntry(CityCode,CityName,Area,Population)
SELECT TN.CityCode, TN.CityName, TN.Area, TN.Population
FROM #OnlineDataBase TN WHERE TN.CityCode NOT IN (SELECT CityLocalDB.CityCode IN FROM LocalFunction as CityLocalDB)


INSERT INTO #tbUpdateEntry(CityCode,CityName,Area,Population)
SELECT TN.CityCode, TN.CityName, TN.Area, TN.Population
FROM #OnlineDataBase TN WHERE TN.CityCode IN (SELECT CityLocalDB.CityCode IN FROM LocalFunction as CityLocalDB
WHERE TN.CityName !=CityLocalDB.CityName )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably see a bigger performance improvement if you replaced the your "IN" and "NOT IN" statements with "EXISTS" and "NOT EXISTS".

Eg:

```
INSERT INTO @tbNewEntry(CityCode,CityName,Area,Population)
SELECT TN.CityCode, TN.CityName, TN.Area, TN.Population
FROM @OnlineDataBase TN 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM LocalFunction as CityLocalDB 
        WHERE 
            CityLocalDB.CityCode = TN.CityCode
    )
```